# Can I verify on my server that a user paid for an Android app through the Google Play Store?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

There appears to be a [Subscriptions and In-App Purchases API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/gp-purchase-status-api.html#subscriptions_api_overview) to verify in-app purchases, but as far as I can tell there is no way to do the same for the app itself through the Google Play Store.

There is an Android API for [verifying licensing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html), but it appears to be on-device only.  I'd like to do the verification against their server from my server, not my app.

With iOS, I can use the [Receipt Validation API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1) to determine both if an app was purchased on the App store and any in-app purchases.  The app sends the receipt to my server, and my server verifies the receipt with Apple's servers.  Is there something analogous for Android?

Comment: I don't believe there's an equivalent to the Receipt Validation API, but you can use the Licence Verification API in Android in the App, and update that on your server? That's about as close as I've managed, anyway

Comment: I don't really want my app to trust the client, which is why I was hoping to validate on the server side.  But if that's not an option... so be it I guess.